# How to create variadic template function to shift the argument values and handles both lvalues and rvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I want to replace these macros with a variadic template that achieves the same thing.

```
#define SHFT2( a, b, c ) do { (a) = (b); (b) = (c); } while(0)
#define SHFT3( a, b, c, d ) do { (a) = (b); (b) = (c); (c) = (d); } while(0)
#define SHFT4( a, b, c, d, e ) do { (a) = (b); (b) = (c); (c) = (d); (d) = (e); } while(0)
```

I have a solution that works for lvalues

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
T first(T t, Ts... ts)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename T>
void shift(T t)
{
    // do nothing
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void shift(T& t, Ts&... ts)
{
    t = first(ts...);
    shift(ts...);
}
```

For example, this works

```
int w = 1;
int x = 2;
int y = 3;
int z = 4;

shift(w, x, y, z);

printf("%d %d %d %d\n", w, x, y, z); // 2 3 4 4
```

But I want to be able to shift in a rvalue at the end

```
shift(w, x, y, z, 5);

printf("%d %d %d %d\n", w, x, y, z); // expect 2 3 4 5
```

I get this error

```
test.cpp:31:2: error: no matching function for call to 'shift'
        shift(w, x, y, z, 5);
        ^~~~~
test.cpp:16:6: note: candidate function [with T = int, Ts = <int, int, int, int>] not viable: expects an l-value for 5th
      argument
void shift(T& t, Ts&... ts)
     ^
test.cpp:10:6: note: candidate function template not viable: requires single argument 't', but 5 arguments were provided
void shift(T t)
```

because you can't reference an rvalue.

How can I make this work in both cases?

Comment: What about the macro you mentioned? I guess it will produce the same kind of error. Assigning something to a literal like 5 anyhow doesn't make sense. Or, are you intending to put an rvalue only at the last position?

Comment: @JunekeyJeon Correct. There will only ever be an rvalue at the last position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a forwarding reference parameter in order to accept both lvalues and rvalues, and `std::forward` to "forward" the value category of the original argument, *i.e.,* convert the parameter to the matching value category.

```
template <typename T>
void shift(T&& t) {
    // do nothing
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
void shift(T1&& t1, T2&& t2, Ts&&... ts) {
    std::forward<T1>(t1) = std::forward<T2>(t2);
    shift(std::forward<T2>(t2), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

Here, `std::forward<T1>(t1)` ensures that `t1` will be assigned to as an lvalue if the argument was an lvalue, and as an rvalue if the argument was an rvalue. For example, `shift(42, x)` will not compile because an rvalue of type `int` cannot be assigned to.

`std::forward<T2>(t2)` ensures that if the argument for `t2` was an lvalue, it will be copied, while if it was an rvalue, it will be moved if possible.

`std::forward<T2>(t2)` and `std::forward<Ts>(ts)...` pass on the value category information to the recursive call.

Comment: Marking this one correct because I think it gives the best/earliest error message when misused: `test.cpp:14:23: error: expression is not assignable
        std::forward<T1>(t1) = std::forward<T2>(t2);`

Answer (score 1):

You'd want something like

```
#include <utility>
// abort
template <class T> void shift(T&&) { }
// assign to lvalue
template<class T1, class T2, class... Ts>
void shift(T1& t1, T2&& t2, Ts&&... ts) 
{
    t1 = std::forward<T2>(t2);
    shift(std::forward<T2>(t2), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

which expects all parameters but the last to be lvalues, where the last may be an lvalue, too.

- Once all parameters but the last one are consumed, the abort `shift(T&&)` is called.
- All other parameters are forwarded as `t1` at some point which is an lvalue reference, ensuring that lvalues have been passed in any slot but the last one.

i.e. `shift(w, x, y, z, 5);` compiles but `shift(w, x, y, 5, z);` or `shift(w, x, y, 5, 5);` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

> because you can't reference an rvalue.

You're declaring parameter as lvalue reference, just change them to [forwarding references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references),  which serve as both lvalue reference and rvalue reference, according to the value category of the passed-in argument. e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
T&& first(T&& t, Ts&&... ts)
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}

template<typename T>
void shift(T&& t)
{
    // do nothing
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void shift(T&& t, Ts&&... ts)
{
    t = first(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    shift(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```